# Partition of unity & intuition behind it.

Tags: intuition, geometric-series

Is there some intuition behind this identity? 
Looks like it should be, but I can't figure it out. 
$$ (1-\alpha)^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha(1-\alpha)^{n-i} = 1 $$
$$ \alpha \in [0; 1]$$
Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 6):

Consider the tossing of a biased coin with probability of heads $\alpha$ and that of tails $1-\alpha$. You keep tossing the coin until you toss a heads.

The probability of you tossing the coin exactly $k$ times before your first heads is $\alpha(1-\alpha)^{k}$. The probability that you toss the coin at least $k$ times before your first heads is $(1-\alpha)^k$ (The first $k$ tosses are tails essentially). Since you will toss a heads at some point of time, $$ (1-\alpha)^{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha(1-\alpha)^{n-i} = 1 $$

The first term represents the probability that you will toss the coin at least $n$ times and the second term sums up the probabilities for all $k\leq n$ that you will toss the coin exactly $k$ times.

Edit: As Arthur said, it is easier to follow the argument if you think of it as "giving up after the $n^{\operatorname{th}}$ tails" as opposed to tossing $n$ tails before the first heads. The argument remains similar for the most part.

Comment: +1 (this is basically the same answer that I wrote, only faster and a bit better structured) I would personally prefer to phrase it as "giving up after the $n$th tails". That way you don't have to get into any infinity shenanigans, or distinctions between "guaranteed" and "probability $1$". For instance, "Since you will toss a heads at some point of time" isn't strictly true.

Comment: I'm not sure I am getting the argument this explanation, for this reasoning in term of probability could only prove that the limit when n goes to infinity of the LHS is $1$. Would it be possible for you to elaborate a little bit more on this?

Comment: @Jeanba As I said in my comment above, if you change it from "Toss a coin until you get heads" to "Toss a coin until you get a heads, but give up after the $n$th toss regardless", there is no need for infinity. The argument becomes a bit easier to follow in my opinion, and $(1-\alpha)^n$ is just the probability that you gave up with no heads.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha \in (0,1)$ you can have the geometric point of view where $1$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit hypercube, and you reach it by starting with a smaller $n$-hypercube of size $1-\alpha$ (then its volume is $(1-\alpha)^n$) and with each value of $i$ from $1$ to $n$ you add the "side part" to transform it into a parallelepiped of size $1$ in $i$ dimensions and size $(1-\alpha)$ in the $(n-i)$ remaining ones, until you reached the unit hypercube.

Comment: I upvoted it as I like  visualizing things in space. I think a drawing for n = 3 would really help visualizing this answer though.